# Flash / AS3 - How do you get the points of a path drawn in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, animation

Is it possible to draw a path in flash, and access the points from AS?

For example if I have a map and I add hidden paths along various roads, I then later want to animate traffic or growing lines along these predefined paths from code.

Comment: Good question - I but I'm not aware of a way to do this. Would happily be proven wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never tried it, but technically it should be possible using a library like [as3swf](https://github.com/claus/as3swf/wiki), which is a SWF parser written in actionscript.

You would have to parse the SWF containing the path using the parser library and then extract the needed coordinates from the output.

That procedure seems horribly backwards to me though. A simpler, more feasible approach would be to draw your paths in Flash, select them and export them using: `File > Export > Export Selection...`, then export as `Adobe FXG`. This will export your Paths as [FXG XML](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/FXG+1.0+Specification) file.

You can then parse the FXG file in flash and extract the path coordinates that are interesting for you. Shouldn't be that hard to implement. Also have a look at the [Path class docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/primitives/Path.html#data), as it contains some information about how coordinates are stored and should be interpreted.

Comment: The problem with either of these methods is that you are loading the files, then processing them without producing their output.  In order use them, you would have to process them again, and show the results onscreen.  Isn't there a way to grab the Sprite's path info, or drawPathData from an *already* created Sprite instance?

Comment: @iND No, sadly that's not possible. The only way is to go the other way round.. eg. Have the data and use the data to draw the path. Having the path won't allow you to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

You might think it reasonable to expect this in the worlds leading 18 year old, scriptable-vector-drawing app, but you would be wrong.

You might be able to get the effect you need by tweening a movieclip along a path, say over 100 frames using the animation tools (gui), then controlling the contents of the movie clip and the playback of the animation via AS3.

Otherwise you will need to draw your paths in Illustrator or equivalent, export via (e.g.) SVG and import the data. This will work as long as you don't actually need to draw the paths, as, obviously, AS3 can only draw Quadratic Beziers, while Illustrator can only draw/export Cubic Beziers.

Comment: Hehe. I won't upvote this as an answer, but if SO had Google +1 or Facebook likes (though I'm grateful it doesn't), I would give one of those.

Answer (score 0):

You can create array of [Point](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Point.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6) objects, save there all checkpoints of your path. And in a moment when you need nicely show your path. You just need to draw it line by line: line from point 1 to point 2, line from point 2 to point 3.. etc.. Better to do this on some separate Sprite, on top of you map object, so you will be able later to delete it easily from the stage.

In this way you can have arrays of points for every path. The only *difficult* part here will be to create all these arrays.

Comment: -1 as this is not practical at all. So you're going to measure every single coordinate you need and write it down in code as an entry in your path array? What if you need to modify some parts of the path? Re-do that whole procedure?

Comment: Practicality depends on how many points he needs to adequately describe the path.  This would remain reasonable for a small-ish number of points.  This starts to break down with a large number of points; I agree there.  In that case, if a user was ambitious, they could create their own drawing application to manage the points for them.

Comment: @bummzack well agreed that this is not the best way to do it. But, I didn't want to store all coordinates inside the code, I was thinking about DB, making call to the server, get the xml with coordinates, put them to the array, draw. And of course there should be a back office tool for editing coordinates. I thought that DB part is pretty obvious if you need to store a lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the points in the path ahead of time, you could store them in an Array or Vector and handle your drawing manually.  Check out the Graphics class for the drawing methods.  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html.

If you don't want to go that route, you could apply some code wizardry to do the work for you.  One potential way to do it, if you knew the starting point: draw your hidden path on a Shape with a certain color (0x00ff0000, fully transparent red, for example).  Then draw your Shape to a BitmapData instance.  Each frame, look for fully transparent red pixels adjacent to your current position (using the getPixel method of BitmapData) that you haven't moved to yet, and then move to that point.  Note, this technique won't support intersections.